# Is moving a constraint into a join more efficient than join and a where clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been trying to test this, but I have doubts about my tests as the timings vary so much.

```
-- Scenario 1
SELECT * FROM Foo f 
    INNER JOIN Bar b ON f.id = b.id 
    WHERE b.flag = true;

-- Scenario 2 
SELECT * FROM Foo f 
    INNER JOIN Bar b ON b.flag = true AND f.id = b.id;
```

Logically it seems like scenario 2 would be more efficient, but I wasn't sure if SQL server is smart enough to optimize this or not.

Comment: Execution plans should be identical.

Comment: Because without knowledge of the how SQL is interpreting the queries, it seems that filtering down the set to be joined before joining would be more efficient than joining everything and then filtering. Marcin is right they do have the same Execution plan. I wasn't familiar with using execution plans - they do the job nicely.

Comment: The headline should probably be changed to explicitly say "inner join" as it is well accepted that for outer joins the executions plans often vary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure why you think scenario 2 would "logically" be `more efficient`. On an `INNER JOIN` everything is basically a filter so SQL Server can collapse the logic to the exact same underlying plan shape. Here's an example from AdventureWorks2012 ([click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibiXt.png)):

[image]

I prefer separating the join criteria from the filter criteria, so will always write the query in the format on the left. However @HLGEM makes a good point, these clauses are interchangeable in this case only because it's an `INNER JOIN`. For an `OUTER JOIN`, it is very important to place the filters on the outer table in the join criteria, else you unwittingly end up with an `INNER JOIN` and drastically change the semantics of the query. So my advice about how the plan can be collapsed only holds true for inner joins.

If you're worried about performance, I'd start by getting rid of `SELECT *` and only pulling the columns you actually need (and make sure there's a covering index).

Four months later, another answer has emerged claiming that there usually will be a difference in performance, and that putting filter criteria in the `ON` clause will be better. While I won't dispute that it is certainly plausible that this could happen, I contend that it certainly isn't the norm and shouldn't be something you use as an excuse to always put all filter criteria in the `ON` clause.

Comment: I will add that if you use left joins, the resust sets will be different between putting the condition in the join or the where clause. So it makes a difference there, but not in performance as much as in results.

Comment: @HLGEM yes, that is true. Also true for cross joins. :-) I only treated inner because that's what was specifically mentioned in the question. Cheers.

Comment: well I knew you knew that, but so few developers seems to be aware of it, I just thought I'd mention it so that someone else reading this question doesn't make an incorrect assumption for their problem.

Answer (score -5):

The accepted answer is correct only for your test case.

An answer to the headline question as stated is ***yes***, moving the constraint to the join condition can greatly improve the query and ensures.  I have seen forms similar to this (but perhaps not exactly)...

```
select * 
  from A
 inner join B
    on B.id = a.id
 inner join C
    on C.id = A.id
 where B.z = 1 and C.z = 2;
```

...not optimize to the same plan as the "on join" equivalents so I tend to use the "on join" constraints as a best practice even for the simpler cases that might have resolved optimally either way.

Comment: Instead of assuring us that this happens, you can provide the actual query with its 2 forms and the 2 different plans that the optimizer produced. Otherwise, your suggestion for best practices collides with the opinions of others, and among them people like Aaron Bertrand and Paul White which are well known in the SQL-Server community.

Comment: While it is *possible* that certain scenarios could demonstrate different optimization paths depending on location of the clause! I suspect it is extremely rare! and I would write the query logically (join criteria = ON, filter criteria = WHERE) unless I have a performance reason to investigate alternatives. You make it sound like my demonstration above is the exception, yet the best proof you can come up with is "it was something like this"? If you want people to listen to your claims, please demonstrate a real case where what you're stating holds true. Otherwise it's just snake oil.

Comment: Yes, I should be able to post something to back up the claim.